# Compile Wireshark with man pages

Tags: wireshark, rhel8

I am trying to compile wireshark 3.6.6 from source on a rhel8 server; but, can not seem to get the man pages installed.  I downloaded the source tarball from wireshark.org. untarred it.  Changed into the wireshark-3.6.6 directory.  Issued the following commands:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"
make
make DESTDIR=/tmp/rpmbuild install
```

perl, python3, GNU 'make', pod2man, & flex are installed.

I can see the binaries; but, I can't see any man pages.  I searched the INSTALL & README files & couldn't see any type of switches for turning the man pages on or off.  Searching the web wasn't any help since "compile wireshark man pages" just links me to the man pages on the web.

Comment: "does not show any research effort"?  I stated that I read the INSTALL & README documents and searched the web & couldn't find any relevant results.  What other research effort do you think I should have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that wireshark-3.6 requires `asciidoctor` to create the man pages.  RHEL 8 ships with `asciidoc`.  Installing `rubygem-asciidoctor` and its dependancies from the epel repository fixes the problem.